# Postgres, best query performance between group by text attribute VS CTE and group by integer

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

With these tables

[image: Tables diagrams]

What is the most efficient way to display videos with at least 2 actors?

Using `GROUP BY` (the type of the attribute is `text`)

```
select v.title from play
    join videos v on play.video_id = v.id
    group by v.title
    having count(v.title) >= 2;
```

Use `CTE` with `SELECT` (the group by is done onto integer attribute)

```
with req as (
    select video_id from play group by video_id having count(*) >= 2
    )
    select title from videos where videos.id in (select video_id from req);
```

Use `CTE` whit `JOIN` (the group by is done onto integer attribute)

```
with req as (
    select video_id from play group by video_id having count(*) >= 2
    )
    select title from videos  join req on videos.id = req.video_id;
```

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` before each query to get infos about executed operations, planning and execution times. Then compare these infos between each query.

Comment: Check the [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: Why ask us?  Measure it and see.  Then if you need help understanding what you have just measured, that might be something we can help with.  Use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to do the measurement, and turn on track_io_timing first if you can.